# Calculations on variables using LaTeX

Tags: calculations

I'm trying to do some basic calculations using values stored on a command, but it doesn't do the calculation:

```
\newcommand{\lenghtHeatExchanger}{0.820}
\newcommand{\heightHeatExchanger}{1.081}
\newcommand{\areaHeatExchanger}{\lenghtHeatExchanger*\heightHeatExchanger}
```

Is there a simple way to do that using LaTeX ?

Thank you.

Comment: LaTeX has limited ability to do math calculations.  Best way is to employ a package that does floating math, such as `fp`, `xfp`, or `tikz`.  By the way, length is spelled leng*th* rather than leng*ht*.

Comment: Can you please show an example of how you'd like to use such macros?

Comment: @egreg - Sorry I didn't really understand your question.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I agree with the use of  fp or xfp but not tikz. TikZ works on top of TeX and has the same limitations but you can add lua

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will suggest to use the `calculator` package and its `\MULTIPLY` command, see documentation [here](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/calculator/calculator.pdf).
BUT: I think that if you could switch to LuaLaTeX it would surely be the best solution!

Comment: Works great and very simple to use, thanks !

Answer (score 7):

[`xfp`](//ctan.org/pkg/xfp) provides a number of `f`loating `p`oint operations:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xfp}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\lengthHeatExchanger}{0.820}
\newcommand{\heightHeatExchanger}{1.081}
\newcommand{\areaHeatExchanger}{\fpeval{\lengthHeatExchanger * \heightHeatExchanger}}

$\verb|\lengthHeatExchanger| = \lengthHeatExchanger$

$\verb|\heightHeatExchanger| = \heightHeatExchanger$

$\verb|\lengthHeatExchanger| \times \verb|\heightHeatExchanger| = \areaHeatExchanger$

\end{document}
```

If needed, it handles calculations on dimensions by converting it to `pt` and managing as a `f`loating `p`oint without the need to strip the dimension manually.

Answer (score 5):

If you're free to employ LuaLaTeX, performing calculations involving macros doesn't require the loading of any external packages, as the following example shows. The solution method exploits the fact that the argument of `\directlua` is expanded automatically. In the current example, `\docalc{\length*\height}` is expanded to `\directlua{tex.sprint(2.5*4)}`; LuaTeX performs the calculation, and the result (`10`) replaces `\docalc{\length*\height}`; hence, it works out to `\newcommand{\area}{10}`.

[image]

Of course, if you needn't store the value of the calculation, you could simply run `$\length \times \height = \docalc{\length*\height}$`.

```
\documentclass{article}
%% The following setup assumes that either pdfLaTeX or LuaLaTeX is in use.
\usepackage{ifluatex} % for '\ifluatex' macro
\ifluatex
   \usepackage{unicode-math} % load 'fontspec' package automatically
   % use \setmainfont and \setmathfont directives as needed...

   % Set up a LaTeX macro to interface with Lua:
   \newcommand\docalc[1]{\directlua{tex.sprint(#1)}}
\else % assume that pdfLaTeX is in use
   \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
   \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\fi
% remainder of preamble...

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\length}{2.5}
\newcommand{\height}{4}

\ifluatex 
  \newcommand{\area}{\docalc{\length*\height}}

  $\length \times \height = \area$
\fi

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you ! I dont know why it doesnt work. I think it's because I never used LuaLaTeX and I'm not sure exaclty how to use it and what comes with it.

Comment: @joseldsm - I assume your TeX system and front-end ediror are set up to compile tex documents with pdfLaTeX. How to switch compilation from pdfLaTeX to LuaLaTeX depends primarily on your editor. Which editing program do you employ?

Comment: I use TeXnicCenter. For the compilation, I have only this for LuaLaTeX : LuaLaTeX -> PDF. But when I compile I have the same error coming several times : "String contains an invalid UTF-8 sequence". That's why I stopped looking for a solution with LuaLaTeX, even if I could have looking on the internet why I'm having those error messages.

Comment: @joseldsm - The `invalid UTF-8 sequence` warning message would appear to be unrelated to what you've posted so far, right? When using LuaLaTeX with utf8-encoded characters, be sure to (a) *not* load the `fontenc` and `inputenc` packages and (b) load the [unicode-math](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/unicode-math) package. And, if you don't want to use the default `Latin Modern` text and math fonts, be sure to specify the preferred fonts via `\setmainfont` and `\setmathfont` directives.

Comment: I have indeed the `fontenc` and `inputenc` packages. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @joseldsm - I've edited my code to highlight which packages should be loaded if either LuaLaTeX or pdfLaTeX is used to compile the program.

Answer (score 0):

The solutions are good. As an update to calculation with variables.
I needed to do basic math for the graphics.
The following example with `\usepackage{xfp}`
using `fpeval` allows constants so they do not need to be defined as macro commands, and you do not necessarily have to make variables for the constants.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xfp}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \x in {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11}
  {
    \node at (-5.0, \fpeval{(11.0-\x)*0.5} ) {$\x$};
  };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```